# gcloud git clone issues - windows 10

Tags: git, gcloud

Would appreciate some help with this one - tried suggestions from related posts to no avail. Windows 10 OS.

**auth** and **init** working fine, but on cloning a cloud repository to local I keep on getting errors

on `gcloud source repos clone default --project=project-1234` I get;

> Cloning into 'C:\Users\Me\default'...
>   ERROR: (gcloud.auth.git-helper) Invalid input line format: [path=].
>   fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
>   You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords are not compatible with private repositories
>   ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', 'https: //source.developers.google.com/p/project-1234/r/default', 'C:\Users\Me\default', '--config', 'credential.helper="gcloud.cmd"']' returned non-zero exit status 128

I have tried a couple of re-installs (Git and GCloud) but no luck in correcting this - any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what version of git you are using by running [git --version]? Also what is gcloud version [gcloud --version]? Also in the output of [git config --list] do you have a value for credential.helper?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall latest version of git (2.8.1) and uncheck "Enable git Credential Manager", this work for me. I´m using Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. I print list version for you Brian

[config version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Urbf.png)

Comment: Please post actual code / command input / output instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.